# Have MetaFont read an arithmetic expression from a file

Tags: output, metafont, bash, arithmetic

I know this is a question that possibly does not belong to pure **TeX**, as **MetaFont** is part of a project to which TeX relates, ie as part of building TeX.
**My question is as follows:**
I **call** MetaFont from my **bash terminal**.
and then provide the `expr` entry (see below).

```
    #mf
This is METAFONT, Version 2.7182818 (TeX Live 2019/Arch Linux) (preloaded base=mf)
**expr
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/source/public/knuth-lib/expr.mf
gimme an expr: 4+5-8+4
>> 5
gimme an expr:
```

Now I wanted, **instead of typing** an expression, that I could write some command to have metafont read a line from a `values.txt` (see below) file containing the expression `4+5-8+4` in the first line e etc.

**values.txt:**

```
4+5-8+4
4+5-8+7
4+5-8+13
```

**My output should be:**

```
5
11
17
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: you could use the commandline `mf expr < values.txt`  but why use `expr` which is just an infinite loop reading standard in, rather than have a normal metafont file as input?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ThankXD! I am trying to use metafont within a python `subprocess` module to automatically read multiple lines as in `values.txt`, perform the operations, and direct each result of each line separately to a `result.txt` file containing each result separated by line respectively with respect to `values.txt` . I will try from now on to draw inspiration from your advice.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Your suggestion solves the whole question but should I close this question?

Comment: I may as well post an answer, we don't get many metafont questions, and egreg is always happy to see me pick up a few points:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I understand :-) kkkk. In the meantime I need to figure out how to write output to a file without printing all the extra commands that are shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use your shell facilities to take standard in and standard out from files, so

```
 mf expr < values.txt  > results.txt
```

would put the results in results.txt:

```
This is METAFONT, Version 2.7182818 (TeX Live 2019) (preloaded base=mf)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/source/public/knuth-lib/expr.mf
gimme an expr: >> 5
gimme an expr: >> 8
gimme an expr: >> 14
gimme an expr: 
! Emergency stop.
...
```

Comment: Thanks now I need to send to an output file only the results. I did `mf expr < values.txt  > results.txt`, but the result.txt file ended up containing all terminal output instead of just the results of operations. I will try this with regex or some functionality in python. Not sure what to limit what should be sent to

Comment: @DiegoBneiNoah `expr.mf` seems to be only 5 lines and is as I say an iinfinite loop so it only ends if you get an error, I'm sure you could write a similar file that output more carefully and accepted some specific term to stop cleanly.

Comment: As I understand it if I modify one of these lines  `string s[]; s1="abra"; path p[]; p1=(0,0)..(3,3); p2=(0,0)..(3,3)..cycle; tracingonline:=1; scrollmode; forever: message "gimme an expr: "; s0:=readstring; show scantokens s0; endfor`.  What kind of programming language is this? MetaPost?

Comment: @DiegoBneiNoah it's metafont (I assumed you knew that to start with???)  metapost is a later system derived from metafont. But metafont is a font design language, what are you using it for if not designing fonts?

Comment: Thanks! I am using to calculate arithmetic and algebraic expressions using MetaFont as explained in the manual. I see it being simpler than writing functions in python. I've already built in fonts but at the moment I'm more interested in this MetaFont math functionality see the advantages over python in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59604469/evaluate-an-almost-algebraic-expression-without-the-symbol-in-python. Also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metafont#Modes_of_operation .

Comment: using metafont for _math_ from python seems a very bizarre choice, but it's a free world:-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103005/discussion-between-diego-bnei-noah-and-david-carlisle).